# Issue with API Request in openedx: Server Error when Modifying Student Grades

Tags: postman, openedx

I am a newcomer to openedx, and I encountered the following issue while testing the API of the openedx platform using Postman. When I use the POST method to test the API at "/grades/v1-gradebook/{course_id}/bulk-update", if I send a request without any content in the body, the server returns a 202 Accepted status.

However, when I include data in the body, like the following:

```
{
    "user_id": 4,
    "usage_key": "block-v1:test+test102+test02+type@sequential+block@016bc6ec071944459c02847b60870d5e"
}
```

the server returns a 500 Internal Server Error. After checking the server logs, I found that the error is caused by:

> "TypeError: string indices must be integers".

I have also tried sending data in other formats or modifying its content, but none of them seem to work.

Can someone please guide me on the correct format and data to be sent to this API to successfully update a student's grade for a specific subsection? Any help on how to use this API properly would be greatly appreciated.